# How to check for Dark Mode in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, ios-darkmode

- How to observe dark mode state in an iOS app
- How to react to changes in dark mode state in an iOS app

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57279700/programmatically-detect-dark-mode-in-swiftui-to-display-appropriate-image/57280180#57280180) for how to do it with SwiftUI.

Answer (score 171, accepted):

UIKit has had UITraitCollection for a while now. Since iOS 9 you could use UITraitCollection to see whether the device supports 3D Touch (a sad conversation for another day)

[In iOS 12](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitraitcollection/1651063-userinterfacestyle), UITraitCollection got a new property: `var userInterfaceStyle: UIUserInterfaceStyle` which supports three cases: `light`, `dark`, and `unspecified`

Since UIViewController inherits UITraitEnvironment, you have access to the ViewController's `traitCollection`. This stores `userInterfaceStyle`.

UITraitEnviroment also has some nifty protocol stubs that help your code interpret when state changes happen (so when a user switches from the Dark side to the Light side or visa versa). Here's a nice coding example for you:

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if self.traitCollection.userInterfaceStyle == .dark {
            // User Interface is Dark
        } else {
            // User Interface is Light
        }

    }


    override func traitCollectionDidChange(_ previousTraitCollection: UITraitCollection?) {
        // Trait collection has already changed
    }

    override func willTransition(to newCollection: UITraitCollection, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
        // Trait collection will change. Use this one so you know what the state is changing to.
    }
}
```

Comment: I thought dark mode was introduced in iOS 13?

Comment: @אוריorihpt You're right https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/visual-design/dark-mode

Comment: Yes, but the UITraitCollection property was introduced in iOS 12

Answer (score 72):

You can use the following code to check for light, or dark mode in your project:

```
func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    switch traitCollection.userInterfaceStyle {
        case .light, .unspecified:
            // light mode detected
        case .dark:
            // dark mode detected
    }
}
```

You can also check for changes in the interface style:

```
override func traitCollectionDidChange(_ previousTraitCollection: UITraitCollection?) {
    super.traitCollectionDidChange(previousTraitCollection)

    let userInterfaceStyle = traitCollection.userInterfaceStyle // Either .unspecified, .light, or .dark
    // Update your user interface based on the appearance
}
```

Just like in macOS since Mojave, you can define images for both light and dark mode in your asset catalogue so that those images will be used automatically:

[image: asset catalogues]

<sub>Taken from [here](https://schiavo.me/2019/implementing-dark-mode/).</sub>