# Programmatically detect dark mode in SwiftUI to display appropriate Image

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, ios-darkmode

In `Assets.xcassets`, there is an ability to add additional images that will automatically switch based on the Appearances. This works well for static images but I'm trying to figure out how to do this for downloaded images.

[image: Image Set]

Is there a way to either set the dark mode version of an `Image` on init or is there a function in SwiftUI that will allow you to detect whether the current appearance is dark so that a different image URL can be served?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You can use `@Environment(\.colorScheme) var colorScheme: ColorScheme` in any view to get whether the device is in dark mode (`.dark`) or light mode (`.light`). Using that information, you can conditionally decide which image to show easily with a ternary operator.

For example, if you have an image named "lightImage" for light mode and "darkImage" for dark mode:

```
@Environment(\.colorScheme) var colorScheme: ColorScheme

var body: some View {
    Button(action: {
        foo()
    }) {
        Image(colorScheme == .light ? "lightImage" : "darkImage")
    }
}
```

Comment: This works, but only for the colorScheme set when the app/view launches. If the user changes the color scheme during runtime, this approach will break your UI.

Comment: What is the right approach so properly handles color scheme changes during runtime?

Comment: To answer myself: you can add `.id(self.colorScheme)` to the view. Works great.

Comment: @KevinRenskers I do not know about you, but colorScheme works just fine for me even if i keep swapping between 'dark' and 'light' mode!?  No need to add any additional code like you stated with `.id(self.colorScheme)`.

Comment: This gives me the error `Cannot find type 'ColorScheme' in scope`

Comment: @Ishmael7 Maybe you need to `import SwiftUI`

Comment: `Property wrappers are not yet supported on local properties` How can I get it when it is in a local property?

Answer (score 3):

There's an `@Environment` variable.

```
@Environment (\.colorScheme) var colorScheme:ColorScheme
```

Here's how I use it to fill an empty Rectangle:

```
Rectangle().fill(Color.fillColor(for: colorScheme))
```

Answer (score 3):

**How to detect dark mode**

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.colorScheme) var colorScheme

    var body: some View {
        Text(colorScheme == .dark ? "In dark mode" : "In light mode")
    }
}
```

Source: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-detect-dark-mode

Answer (score 0):

In XCode 13 :

```
@SwiftUI.Environment (\.colorScheme) var colorScheme:ColorScheme
```