# Possible to reload app when dark/light mode changes?

Tags: ios, swift, ios13, ios-darkmode

My app makes extensive use of CAGradientLayers which apparently do not automatically update their colors when dark/light mode is switched. They will update their colors when the app is closed and reopened though.

Im aware i can use the following code to detect the change and reload each view individually

```
 override func traitCollectionDidChange(_ previousTraitCollection: UITraitCollection?) {
        // 
    }
```

However I am looking for a fix that does not require me to update each view individually.  Is there a way to detect a light/dark mode change (possibly within the app delegate) and force the entire app to reload itself (as if it had been force closed and reopened)?

---

### Edit with Solution:

The app cannot be reloaded in the way I'd originally imagined however there is a fairly simple solution that is much cleaner.

As stated in the accepted answer, a subclass of `UIView` can be created that contains a `CAGradientLayer` as a sublayer.  You can then override `traitCollectionDidChange` to reload the view automatically when the system style changes.  The key is to remember that `UIColors` automatically update when system style changes but `CGColors` do not automatically update.  So you'll need to store the original `UIColor` for the gradient and convert the `UIColor` back to a `CGColor` every time the system style is updated.

Linked below is a Github Gist with a very basic implementation of a "Gradient View" that will automatically respond to light & dark mode changes.  It can be added as a subview to other views or modified as needed.

[GradientView.swift](https://gist.github.com/Alec-Barton/4b995bd8f5e6e7fc36bcb5ccbb56fb30)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Check for iOS Dark Mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56457395/how-to-check-for-ios-dark-mode)

Comment: Unclear what you could be asking. What does "force the entire app to reload itself" even mean? What does "quicker fix" mean? There is nothing to fix and everything is perfectly quick. You receive `traitCollectionDidChange`, you redraw your gradients using your alternate set of colors. Apple has explained this thoroughly in the WWDC 2019 video on this topic.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/214/?time=1393 completely explains this, so just _watch_ it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no way to "reload your app" in this way. The issue arises because `CAGradientLayer` uses `CGColor`, which doesn't dynamically adapt to the system style.

I resolved the issue by wrapping a `UIView` around the gradient layer that implements `traitCollectionDidChange` to update the gradient's colors accordingly. Maybe you can do the same and use this as subview instead of a sublayer.

Answer (score 2):

You could create a super class UIViewController that override `traitCollectionDidChange`